# Security - See which user exported reports

Tags: security, data-export, custom-reports

Is there a way which I can know which user made export to report?

Details about the user, date and time and the report name?

(A free tool will be great).

Thanks!

Comment: Yes I read about this tool, I'm looking for a free tool like a package from the app exchange (this is the business request)..

Comment: Report export is only trackable through the paid Event Monitoring feature.

Comment: Thank you :) ...